# Break points and Stepping through the code in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas

In Excel VBA, we can step through a block of code by pressing the `F8` key. Even inside a `for` loop, we can step though one line at a time by pressing the F8 key.

Also, we can add break points by pressing the `F9` key. In order to halt the code running further more after a certain break-point.

These will help us to easily Debug & Test the code effortlessly.

My question is, Is there any similar shortcuts available in Python/Pandas? is it possible in python to step line by line inside a `For` loop and/or add break points like VBA?

Comment: I'm using Jupyter notebook. is it possible in it?

Comment: For this you'd need an IDE, if you've installed anaconda you could use Spyder. Altough I'd recommend Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

There's a [python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) that you can import. `pdb.set_trace` will add checkpoints where you can step through code. There are also notebook [implementations](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pdb) of this as well.

```
import pdb

x = 'hello'
print(x)
pdb.set_trace()
y = 'world'
print(y)
```

As of 3.7, there's a built-in `breakpoint` that removes the need to import pdb.

Comment: What exactly confuses you? The idea is to run`set_trace` where you want to pause code execution. This acts as a breakpoint similar to what you described. From there you can check variable values and step through code line by line. I also noticed there's a new built-in `breakpoint`, so you don't have to import pdb, FYI.